# Mercurial no longer working in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, mercurial

I have been using Mercurial inside NetBeans for a while now.

For the past few weeks now Windows Explorer has been crashing for various reasons, including every time I right click.

Finally someone suggested I try uninstalling TourtoiseSVN and TortoiseHG since they affect Windows Explorer directly. I uninstalled both last week since I don't ever use them (I either user the NetBeans interface or use the command line interface.) Since then my Windows Explorer stopped crashing.

Today I noticed that in NetBeans it is no longer showing me any of the Mercurial features. I pull up a command prompt and its not working their either. It seems like uninstalling TortoiseHG also uninstalled Mercurial altogether, which was not intended.

I went to http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Download to download the 64bit 1.8.4 .exe version of Mercurial for Windows. I installed it, and I can now use the command line. However it is still now working in NetBeans.

Does NetBeans require Tortoise to work? Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had to go to:

> Tools > Options > Misc > Versioning > Mercurial

and choose the new `Mercurial Executable Path`

[Instructions here.](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mercurial.html#settingUp)